# Docker compose access service directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have api and static services in docker compose file,

```
services:
  static:
    build: ./static
    volumes:
      - uploads:/app/uploads
  api:
    build: ./api
volumes:
  uploads:
```

In structure it's looks like

```
api
 Dockerfile
 uploads.js -> uploads request api handler
static
 Dockerfile
 uploads -> directory for saving static content
```

How I can access uploads directory inside static service from api service? Code above says that uploads directory doesn't exists when I try access it from api service.

Comment: Think of each container as a separate computer. How would you do it if each program ran on its own computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you map the volume to the `api` service as well, it'll be available in both.

Like this:

```
services:
  static:
    build: ./static
    volumes:
      - uploads:/app/uploads
  api:
    build: ./api
    volumes:
      - uploads:/app/uploads
volumes:
  uploads:
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Still have the same issue.

Comment: I add structure for better understanding what I can try to do.